# Is it possible foreach with outside declared variable

Tags: c#, foreach

Usually for each writes like this

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
foreach(int a in intList)
{
  if(a > 5){
     break;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
int a=0;
foreach(a in intList)
{
  if(a > 5){
     break;
  }
}
//do something to **a** here
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to keep variable `a` after the loop. I know it can be assign to a variable outside the loop. But im looking for something short.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible. Following C# spec, here is the `foreach` loop syntax:

```
foreach-statement:
foreach   (   local-variable-type   identifier   in   expression   )
    embedded-statement
```

As you can see, `local-variable-type` is part of the grammar here, so it's required in the code to make it a correct C# code.

You should use LINQ and `FirstOrDefault` to get similar behavior in much cleaner way:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
int a = intList.FirstOrDefault(x => x > 5)
```

The difference is, if you don't find an item matching the condition in your list, `a` will be set to `default(int)`, not the value of last item in your collection.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is to find the first value in your list that's greater than 5, then something like this would be less code, and cleaner:

```
 int a = intList.Find(x => x > 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Else you can do this....

```
       List<int> intList = new List<int>();
        int a=0;
        foreach(int b in intList)
        {
          if(b > 5){
             a = b;
             break;
          }
        }
        //do something to **a** here
```

Comment: `a = b` should happen before `if` statement to have the same meaning OP wants to achieve.